# ArrayList в параметрах объекта

Tags: java, массивы, объекты, arraylist, параметры

Меня интересует как в параметрах объекта использовать ArrayList. Например есть описание объекта Shelf

```
class Shelf {
    private int id;
    private static int staticId = 10101;
    private String description;
    private ArrayList<Item> items;

    public Shelf(String description, ArrayList<Item> items) {
        this.id = staticId;
        staticId++;
        this.description = description;
        this.items = items;
    }
    public void setItems(ArrayList<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

Есть несколько предметов

```
Item i = new Item("Shelf", 1, 12, "Shelf", v);
Item ii = new Item("Frozen", 3, 150, "120*250cm", v);
Item cup = new Item("Coffee cup", 1, 5, "A cup for coffee" ,v);
```

Нужно в параметр `items` положить что нибудь, например cup.

```
Shelf emptyShelf = new Shelf("Shelf for cups", cup);
```

Это так не работает.
Как добавить `cup` в `emptyShelf`?

Наверное я не правильно формулирую свой вопрос, и по этому не могу найти ответ в гугле.
Буду очень благодарен, если кто то поймёт и поможет :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну если я правильно понял, то можно вот так сделать:

Измените ваш конструктор класса Shelf:

```
private int id;
private static int staticId = 10101;
private String description;
private ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

public Shelf(String description, Item...items) {
    this.id = staticId;
    staticId++;
    this.description = description;
    this.items.addAll((Arrays.asList(items));
}
```

Ну а потом при создании нового объекта Shelf можете положить в параметры items, нужное количество items через запятую:

```
    Item table = new Item("Shelf", 1, 12, "Shelf", v);
    Item bottle = new Item("Frozen", 3, 150, "120*250cm", v);
    Item cup = new Item("Coffee cup", 1, 5, "A cup for coffee" ,v);

    Shelf emptyShelf = new Shelf("Shelf for cups", cup);
    Shelf emptyShelf = new Shelf("Shelf for cups", table, bottle);
```

Comment: `this.items.addAll((Arrays.asList(items)` тут будет `NullPointerException` т.к. `this.items` не инициализирован

Comment: @Roman Konoval благодарю, не заметил. Получается только если пустым листом инициализировать переменную в этом способе. Поправил

Answer (score 2):

Вы ищете способ создать массив из элементов.

Есть несколько вариантов, которые могут сработать в зависимости от ваших потребностей.

### Arrays.asList

`Arrays.asList(cup)` создаст массив и его можно сразу передать, как параметр:

```
Shelf emptyShelf = new Shelf("Shelf for cups", Arrays.asList(cup));
```

Нужно иметь ввиду, что `asList` возвращает массив, размер которого нельзя менять, т.е. нельзя добавлять или удалять элементы. Нельзя будет добавить позже элементы так:

```
emptyShelf.getItems().add(ii); // бросит UnsupportedOperationException
```

Но при этом можно менять отдельные элементы в массиве:

```
emptyShelf.getItems().set(0, ii); // заменит первый элемент
```

Есть вариант это обойти в конструкторе:

```
Shelf(..., List<Items> items) {
   this.items = new ArrayList<>;
   this.items.addAll(items);
}
```

### Collections.singltonList

Похоже немного на `Arrays.asList` с одним элементом, но возвращает полностью неизменяемый массив. Даже `set` не будет работать.

### Вручную создать ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
items.add(cup);
Shelf emptyShelf = new Shelf("Shelf for cups", items);
```

### Lists.newArrayList из библиотеки guava

Самый удобный способ если требуется изменяемый объект, но требует внешнюю библиотеку:

```
Shelf emptyShelf = new Shelf("Shelf for cups", Lists.newArrayList(cup));
```